# Aggregating lists in Google Sheets based on weights

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how generate an ordered list based on the weights of items in several other lists.
Here's the criteria

1. The number of items in the lists likely won't change (say 20 per list)
2. The items in the list may change (a lot). new items might appear
3. The higher in a list the more weight given
4. The items with the most weight are at the top of the final list

Example

```
name (weight)

List 1
Bob (100)
Fred (95)
Mary (90)
James (85)

List 2
Mary (100)
Fred (95)
Kate (90)
James (85)
Alan (80)
```

Final list would automatically come out as
Fred (195)
Mary (190)
James (160)
Bob (100)
Kate (90)
Alan (80)

I'm not looking for an answer as I realise I haven't even given my own thoughts. I've tried various sorting functions in google Sheets but I think I'm just way off. Can someone point me to a resource or a function/script to investigate, please?

Comment: Just to mention that the names will be auto-populated from another app, but the weights I added myself. I guess a second auto column could perform that function

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT({A2:A5; A8:A12}, " ()"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2)''"), 
 {"@", "\(#\)"})),,9^9)))
```

[image]